# Sencha Cmd: multiple versions of app.json

Tags: sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

I'm looking to release several versions of an app with an identical codebase differing only in the resources packaged. My current approach is keeping one copy of app.json for each different type of deployment, and copying it on top the the app.json file when I need to build.

I would like to be able to do something like: sencha app build content_one.json android or sencha app build content_three.json ios and have the build process use the specified file to package up the resources for the native files.

EDIT: Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61

According to [the only builds documentation I could find](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/microloader.html#Build_Profiles) <strike>it looks like I may be able to add more to the 'bulids' section (like 'css', 'resources' and 'js' objects)</strike> <--(you cannot).

This isn't exactly what I was hoping for because I'll have to create android-content_one and ios-content_one entries into the 'builds' object. Ideally I would be able to run **sencha app build content_one.json android** or something to that nature.

EDIT "SOLVED":
I was able to "solve" my issue by writing a custom script that copies the build configuration file onto the app.json then executes the build script.

I'm leaving this question open and unanswered in case anyone else stumbles across it and has a better solution.

Thanks ahead of time for any input.

Comment: Depending on what version of Sencha Cmd you're using, there should be configurable build targets under a `build` object -- and presumably you could have unique sets of `resources` defined within the custom targets.